# Heroku host with Angular Client and express server in same folder?

Tags: angular, express, heroku

I am using Heroku for hosting my Express server and Angular web app - At this moment I am using two seperate app folders. One for server and one for client. This also means that I have to pay for two hobby accounts.

My question: Will it have any negative consequences if I was to merge the two projects together?

Thanks

Comment: It's largely a matter of opinion, unless you want to start using server side rendering

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can easily serve your Angular client app from within your express server using the [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) middleware.
That way you have only 1 Heroku app to worry about.
On the other hand, that would typically mean having your client and server code in the same git repo. In some scenarios you might want to maintain them in separate repos, which might justify having separate Heroku apps for them.